# Can a non-Ravenclaw student enter the Ravenclaw dormitory if they correctly answer the riddle?

Tags: harry-potter, ravenclaw

When a Ravenclaw wants to enter their dorm, they have to answer a question instead of a password (which would presumably only known to house members):

> “What? Isn’t there just a password?”
>
> “Oh no, you’ve got to answer a question,” said Luna.
>
> — *Deathly Hallows*, chapter 29 (*The Lost Diadem*)

Does this mean that any student, Ravenclaw or not, can enter just by correctly answer the riddle? For instance, could Hermione (a Gryffindor) figure out the riddle and then walk right in?

The reason I ask is that it that this seems to be the only dormitory where someone unauthorized can enter without a member of the house sharing secret information. For instance, the only way a non-Gryffindor can enter the Gryffindor dorm is if a Gryffindor shares the password (or they allow themselves to be overheard). But unauthorized access to the Ravenclaw dorms does not require a Ravenclaw to share information that they shouldn't tell anyone.

Comment: This would go any common room, I suppose... Gryffindors could share the password; Hufflepuffs could share the secret rhythm to tap the barrels; Slytherins, I forget how they get in... but I think it is also a password.

Comment: Nah, you just [walk in](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YY-qC0Mev4k)

Comment: @Skooba Slytherins have a password too. But Ravenclaw is the only one where you can enter without a member of the house telling you information they are supposed to keep secret.

Comment: @Thunderforge - The old pottermore welcome message strongly implies that *only a Ravenclaw* (or someone very very clever) could access the common room *because the challenges are so devilishly clever*.

Comment: They could yes, but they'd also have to get past the Ravenclaw Battle Laser Turret once inside. The turret would fire at anyone who didn't have a wand attuned to the Ravenclaw dorm. There was a section of the book where this happened to Hermoine, but was left out of the final draft.

Comment: I would honestly think this makes the Ravenclaw room even *more* secure than the other rooms. Slytherin, Hufflepuff, and Gryffindor are all protected by a method that only changes periodically. In order to gain access, all you need to do is hide near the entrance and pay attention, or use some charm to snoop remotely. To enter Ravenclaw...you can't do that...you actually have to be able to answer the question it asks, and is thus harder to breach than something that can be cracked by being sneaky enough to fool a First Year.

Comment: @guildsbounty I guess that's only true if the riddle changes after the last one is solved. If there's a "riddle of the week" or whatever, then it's just as insecure as the others.

Comment: @RyanJ  Where can I read/read about the scene with Hermione in Ravenclaw that was cut?

Comment: @Baard Kopperud: [On Wikipedia.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Irony)

Comment: @Thunderforge: Well, it **does** change after the last one is solved. After Luna solves the phoenix question, Carrow is asked about vanished objects instead.

Comment: You'd also need to know where to knock in order to receive the riddle in the first place. Therefore it's impossible to get into ANY of the common rooms without insider information.

Answer (score 52, accepted):

### Yes (probably).

Professor McGonagall (a Gryffindor) enters the common room by answering the password challenge in *Harry Potter and the Deathly Hallows*

> ‘Certainly, if you wish it,’ said Professor McGonagall, with awful coldness. There was a genteel tap of the knocker and the musical voice asked, again, ‘Where do vanished objects go?’
>
> ‘Into non-being, which is to say, everything,’ replied Professor McGonagall.
>
> ‘Nicely phrased,’ replied the eagle doorknocker, and the door swung open.

This is backed up by the [article on Pottermore](https://www.pottermore.com/features/6-reasons-to-get-excited-if-youre-sorted-into-ravenclaw)

> For a house that thrives from bountiful brains, it is not at all
> surprising that **to get into Ravenclaw Tower, one must complete a
> riddle.**

Note, there's no mention of house affiliation being required to get into **any** of the common rooms. You simply need to fulfill the entry requirements (typically a password).

---

That being said, the original "[Ravenclaw Welcome Message](https://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20110831120945AAsJYuN)" from the Pottermore website seems wildly overconfident about the security afforded by their challenge/response password.

> When you rap on the door, this knocker will ask you a question, and **if
> you can answer it correctly, you are allowed in.** This simple barrier
> has kept out everyone but Ravenclaws for nearly a thousand years.

Comment: Don't professors have special permission to answer any dorm anyway? I guess I'm more wondering about students. I'll update the question.

Comment: @Thunderforge - I've found a couple of other sources. For my money, none of the common rooms' security seems more than superficially effective. It's simply part of the "*your house is your new family*" whimsy rather than an actual barrier.

Comment: It is possible that part of the _magic_ of the knocker is that if the seeker-of-admittance is actually a Ravenclaw (or faculty) then it asks a question that that seeker can answer, otherwise it asks a question that the imposter cannot answer.  Yes, it would have to somehow _know_ who was a Ravenclaw, but then again, the Triwizard cup knows who is best to represent each school given nothing more than a slip of paper with the supplicant's name, so the magic "technology" exists ...

Comment: Wow, I find it hard to believe that there has never, ever been a non-Ravenclaw student who has correctly answered the riddle in 1,000 years. Still, if that's what an official source says, it's correct I guess.

Comment: @Thunderforge - that information clearly came from a Ravenclaw, and we know that one common fault of highly intelligent people is that they often believe in their own infallability in intellectual matters when it is not, in fact, true.

Comment: @Thunderforge - The welcome letters are now *not quite canon*. They were written by JKR but they've been scrubbed from the site.

Comment: @Richard My welcome letter is still available, but it is attached at the bottom of my profile. So, I think now you *must be* sorted into a house to read the welcome message for it.

Comment: @Skooba - Ah, I stand corrected then. I joined the site when it was still in closed testing and never got a welcome message when I was sorted.

Comment: What's interesting about this is that McGonagall was a Hatstall, and almost got sorted into Ravenclaw... so we know she had the brains to be in that House... it would be interesting if there was an example of a non-Ravenclaw who wasn't a Hatstall-with-Ravenclaw who'd made it in...

Comment: I think @Richard has made the most relevant point here - this is a school dormitory inside a very safe building  (from outsiders anyway). I hardly think it's a month's detention for going in the wrong common room.

Comment: @ThurGog - the faculty will do nothing, probably, but otherwise it depends on _which_ common room.  The Slytherins will likely torture you.  The Hufflepuffs will offer to split their gruel with you, humble though it be.  The Ravenclaws will look down their nose at you and mock you with the scorn that only a graduate student in an obscure field can muster towards the uneducated.  The Gryffindors will laugh while the Weasely twins experiment with some untested Wheezes on your person.

Comment: Perhaps it's as simple as victory by definition: if you can answer the riddle, the knocker considers you a Ravenclaw no matter what the Sorting Hat says.

Comment: That Pottermore quote seems obviously mistaken; McGonagall was not nor ever a Ravenclaw, and she got in very quickly.

Comment: @TylerH - as TheGiantofLannister pointed out, she was on the verge of being sorted into Ravenclaw, she's very clever and the challenge password seems largely to be a bit of fun rather than a super-serious barrier given that a skilled wizard could easily fly into the tower.

Comment: @Richard Okay, so she's a smart girl, but she was still never in Ravenclaw. Same applies to Hermione.

Comment: @davidbak Note that Amicus and Alecto would be considered faculty, but needed Flitwick and then McGonagall to open the door for them. I'm pretty sure the seeker doesn't change the riddle level depending on who you are. If you are clever enough to correctly answer it, you are admitted into the room.

Comment: @Ángel That's somewhat confirmed in Deathly Hallows. Luna comments on "today's riddle being x" (possibly this week, I'm not sure), suggesting that the riddle changes based on time and not skill

Comment: @Morgen That was my first thought. After all, it's said many times over that most wizards aren't very strong in logic, much less puzzles. If you've got what it takes, there's a lot of Ravenclaw in you, even if you've got a stronger "desire" that topped that for the hat.

Comment: Probably worth clarifying that one Pottermore quote is a secondary source and that the other is written from the in-universe point-of-view of a prideful Ravenclaw perfect trying to impress first years.

Answer (score 18):

Professor McGonagall entered Ravenclaw Tower in *Deathly Hallows* by correctly answering the eagle's riddle.

> There was a genteel tap of the knocker and the musical voice asked, again, ‘Where do vanished objects go?’
>   ‘Into non-being, which is to say, everything,’ replied Professor McGonagall.
>   ‘Nicely phrased,’ replied the eagle doorknocker, and the door swung open.
>   <sub>*Deathly Hallows* - Chapter thirty - *The Sacking of Severus Snape* - Page 479 - Bloomsbury</sub>

Professor McGonagall is a Gryffindor.

Comment: Don't professors have special permission to answer any dorm anyway? I guess I'm more wondering about students. I'll update the question.

Comment: @Thunderforge - Logically they ought to. However, the fact that she bothered with the riddle strongly implies she did not.

Comment: Another question is: How intelligent is the knocker?  McGonagall's answer is somewhat brief, also apparently self-contradicting, and in any event, requires some interpretation.  How does the knocker manage it?  (Potential answer:  It crowdsources the answer to all (or a committee of) graduated Ravenclaws, like a magical version of Amazon's Mechanical Turk.)  Anyway, has it been working off a set list of questions for the last thousand years (perhaps with repeats?) or does it generate its own questions?

Comment: @Thunderforge - w.r.t. the professors having special permission - the Carrows were unable to get in without assistance from other faculty (hence, McGonagall's assistance).

Comment: @davidbak Didn't we hear Luna say the same answer at some other point? So I believe there is "stock answer".

Comment: @Skooba Luna's question was "Which came first, the phoenix or the flame?", right?

Comment: @davidbak Ah could be!... answer was "a circle has no beginning"

Comment: @davidbak, re *"...set list of questions...?"* —it's magic!

Comment: McGo WAS a Gryffindor. At the time she answers the riddle, she's a teacher, so I think the Pottermore text doesn't apply to her. :)